# Enforce initialization behaviour in abstract class constructor for all future derived classes

Tags: c++, abstract-class, virtual-functions, pure-virtual

I'm deriving from an existing input field class from the Qt Library (not necessary to be familiar with it), where I'm adding a text validator that checks for valid inputs (using the QLineEdit validation options) and some further functionalities/overrides.

For this I create a pure virtual class called `ConstrainedQLineEdit` which derives from `QLineEdit`, from which then I implement specific input fields (e.g. `PasswordQLineEdit`). Here a *simplification* of my implementation:

**Abstract Base class:**

```
class ConstrainedQLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
Q_OBJECT // QT macro that implements observer pattern with signals/slots among others (not relevant)
public:
  virtual ~ConstrainedQLineEdit()
  {
      // delete validator;
  }

protected:
  ConstrainedQLineEdit(QWidget* parent = nullptr)
      : QLineEdit(parent) // , validator(nullptr)
  {
      _initialize();
  }

  virtual void _initialize()
  {
      QString validatorInformation = _getValidatorInformation();
      // validator = new Validator{validatorInformation};
      // further logic 
  }

  virtual QString _getValidatorInformation() const = 0;
  // Validator validator;
  // Further variables and necessary overrides of QLineEdit
};
```

**Derived class for passwords**

```
class PasswordQLineEdit : public ConstrainedQLineEdit
{
  Q_OBJECT // idem
public:
  PasswordQLineEdit(QWidget* parent = nullptr)
      : ConstrainedQLineEdit(parent)
  {}

  virtual ~PasswordQLineEdit() = default;

protected:
  QString _getValidatorInformation() const override
  {
      QString validatorInformation;
      // logic generating the information
      return validatorInformation;
  }
};
```

**Executable**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    PasswordQLineEdit passwordQLineEdit;
    passwordQLineEdit.show();
    return application.exec();
}
```

Upon executing I get the following error (without debugger the application crashes segmentation-fault style):

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
```

**My question**:

I'm aware that it is frowned upon to call a virtual function from the base class constructor since it can lead to exactly this kind of problems. I'm also aware I could just put the initialization in the derived-class constructor.

However, this is a base class that my team will use in the future to create further custom fields, and I want to specifically enforce (or pre-define) the behaviour of how derived classes are constructed so that other team-members really only have to define a constructor that passes the same arguments and then the validation logic via `QString _getValidationInformation() override` and be done with it.

Any design recommendations to achieve this *without* breaking the class structure (I'm overriding further virtual functions of `QLineEdit` and there's additional logic)?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm aware that it is frowned upon to call a virtual function from the
> base class constructor

It is not only "frowned upon", it is wrong. Writing such code will lead to bugs. Your error comes from the fact that your child class virtual method is never called, in the construction process, only the base class methods are called. Hence, it tries to call the `_getValidatorInformation()` from the base class, but it has not been implemented, hence the error. If you had provided a default implementation, then the compiler would have said nothing and you would have ad bugged code.

What I would suggest is to use a factory function to create your object. The factory function would be responsible to

1. Create the object.
2. Validate the preconditions.

Some pseudo code to show the idea:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<ConstrainedQLineEdit> Create(EType type_)
{
    std::unique_ptr<ConstrainedQLineEdit> lineEdit;

    switch(type_)
    {
        case EType::Password:
            lineEdit = std::make_unique<PasswordQLineEdit>();
      
        // You can extend and add types here...
    }

    // At this point, construction is completed. You can use virtual methods!
    lineEdit->Initialize();

    return lineEdit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bob. Yes, I usually use a factory pattern for this kind of cases. But maybe I didn't mention that these objects are used in the Qt Designer (a GUI designer based on markup), from where the UI files are created automatically, so there's no control over the methods called, create them in a factory or calling an initialisation method (otherwise I would have used those). Mostly, they must be backwards compatible with our previous uses of QLineEdit (where no factory/init are called). I solved this by re-implementing the setVisible() method which is called everytime the item is shown.

Comment: @MichelH I am not sure about the Qt Designer limitations. Maybe you could use a decorator then? Instead of using "plain inheritance", you could create some sort of `PasswordQLineEditDecorator` that would be in charge of adding the additional logic. The decorator would hide an instance of the `QLineEdit` to validate and would add validation on top of it. Everyone would share the same interface.

Comment: Isn't a decorator meant to be applied at runtime. As I said before, I cannot intercept the process creation or construction of the custom object. Furthermore I need to override virtual functions of the parent object, which I won't be able to do through a decorator (at least I think so).